# Is there a more efficient way to reformat a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, wide-format-data

I'm working on an anomaly detection model for CPU data and my current dataframes are structured like this (with 10k+ servers and 168 hours):

| Server | Hour1 | Hour2 | Hour3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | val1.1 | val1.2 | val1.3 |
| server2 | val2.1 | val 2.2 | val2.3 |

I need it to be in a structure like this:

| Server | time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | 0 | value0 |
| server1 | 1 | value1 |
| server2 | 0 | value0 |
| server2 | 1 | value1 |

The problem is there are 10k+ servers and 168 hourly values for each, so it's taking an eternity to iterate over. Is there a more efficient way to do this transformation?

My current attempt is creating a new df with nested for loops like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for n in range(0,167):
        new_df.loc[len(new_df.index)] = row
        new_df.iat[len(new_df.index)-1, 2] = n

for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        new_df_ts = row[2]
        if(row[0] == r[0]):
            new_df.iat[index, 3] = df.iat[i, 2 + new_df_ts]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If possible try to explain your issue in words, don't just post the input data and desired output, that means the search engine, indexing and tagging won't be able to find similar questions.

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Pandas: transform column names to row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746702/pandas-transform-column-names-to-row-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: transform column names to row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746702/pandas-transform-column-names-to-row-values)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853463/convert-dataframe-hourly-values-in-columns-to-a-serie-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Server  Hour1   Hour2   Hour3
server1 val1.1  val1.2  val1.3
server2 val2.1  val2.2  val2.3"""), sep="\t")
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, "Hour", "Server", "Time") \
    .rename(columns={"Hour": "Value"}) \
    .reset_index()
```

which results in

```
    Server  Time    Value
0  server1     1   val1.1
1  server2     1   val2.1
2  server1     2   val1.2
3  server2     2   val2.2
4  server1     3   val1.3
5  server2     3   val2.3
```

Alternatively, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then strip the `Hour` text out of the `Time` column.

```
df = df.melt("Server", var_name="Time")
df["Time"] = df["Time"].str.strip("Hour").astype(int)
```

Then do whatever additional processing is required on the `Time` and `Value` columns, such as subtracting 1 from the time period. Use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) or [`df["Value"].str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to alter values if needed.